# Azure says an Alert Rule exists with the same name, but it also says it doesn't

Tags: azure, azure-alerts

I have several environments that I need to set a list of Alert Rules for. I've set 5 up for QA and started to add them to UAT. Because you cannot rename a rule, I have had to delete and recreate a few, and Azure tells you it make take a few minutes to show up.

However, after in-page and browser refreshes, going to get a coffee and refreshing again, I do not have a Rule Alert in UAT for 10 exceptions in 5 minutes.

[image]

Yet when I try to create one I get this:

[image]

So it exists....but where can I see this rule, or delete it? I've removed all filters in the Alert Rules page (first image) already and it doesn't show

Comment: Hello @Red , Could you please filter by this check the Show hidden types checkbox
Filter and list by Type == microsoft.insights/metricalerts then select the relevant alert rules and  Delete.. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Where is this "Show Hidden Types" checkbox? It seems to be hidden

Comment: Could you please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-troubleshoot-metric#metric-alert-rules-still-defined-on-a-deleted-resource , Actually this is for deleted resources.

Comment: May i know ,Does it still not appear if you try to select log search in signal type [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf7rj.png

Comment: "Show Hidden Types" is on the resource group. ATS-UAT in my case. Checking that shows you all the Alert Rules too. I can't say if it would help delete them if they aren't showing, because now it *is* showing in the Alert Rules page. Maybe because of time, maybe because I ticked that box

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround could able to find and delete the alert rule:

- To view the **alert** and delete them we need to filter them accordingly to our **resource group ,subscription, signal type** as below:

[image]

Refresh and then navigate to your target Rule that want to delete
[image]

For more information please refer the below MS DOCS:

- [Create, view, and manage activity log alerts by using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-activity-log)
- [How to update alert rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-resource-move)

Comment: With no filtering at all the rule does not appear in the list to be deleted. This was my initial issue. Please explain how restricting the list will make more appear

Comment: Hello @Red, Could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-troubleshoot-metric#cant-find-the-metric-to-alert-on---virtual-machines-guest-metrics) .

Comment: That's a link to finding metrics (not alerts) on virtual machines (not using them). I found what I needed in the resource type already. I was pointing out that you are trying to help, but haven't read the details of the questions